# Correct implementation of Qiskit QAOA

Tags: qiskit, programming, qaoa, qubo

I've been dealing with a QAOA implementation of a QUBO problem. In order to do this, I converted my QUBO matrix to a `QuadraticModel`. Once done, I have used `Hamiltonian, offset  = mdl.to_ising()` to generate a `Hamiltonian` and `offset`, with `mdl` being my `QuadraticProgram`.

Once done, I went on to verify theoretically that the ground state energy of this Hamiltonian tallies with results an annealer. In order to do this, I used:

`min_val = NumPyMinimumEigensolver(Hamiltonian)`

Sure enough, this matches. The ground state energy when added with the `offset` value brings the value to 0. Now when I am trying to implement a QAOA, I use the following lines of code. I am aware that I am using deprecated code but I'm not sure this contributes to the problem.

```
aqua_globals.random_seed = np.random.default_rng(123)
seed = 10598
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend, seed_simulator=seed, seed_transpiler=seed)
qaoa = QAOA(quantum_instance=quantum_instance, p = 1)
qaoa_optimizer = MinimumEigenOptimizer(qaoa)
result = qaoa_optimizer.solve(mdl)
```

This gives me `optimal function value: 2.0` which isn't the result I am looking for.

I think I'm going wrong somewhere in the implementation of the QAOA, but I'm not sure where. Any help in this regard would be absolutely stellar!

Comment: Try to increase your $p$ value (that might help) and rerun your calculation multiple times. You might very well just getting stuck in a local minimum during the optimization step.

Comment: I tried that by increasing p from 1 till 10 but unfortunately didn't work :(